# knockout - Bring checked checkboxes on top of the list using foreach

Tags: sorting, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

```
<div data-bind="foreach: lists">
    <div class="checkbox list-item">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isSelected, click: $parent.list, disable: $parent.disableInput()"/> <span data-bind="text: note">
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to do the checked checkboxes to move on top. When I click the unchecked checkbox, it needs to move on top. When I click the checked checkbox, it needs to move back down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need an intermediate object to hold the sorted list. Something like:

```
const sorted_lists = ko.pureComputed(() => {
    return lists.sort(a => a.isSelected ? -1 : 0);
});
```

Then you point your `foreach` to this computed value:
`<div data-bind="foreach: sorted_lists">...`